# How to learn programming and designing?

Tags: undergraduate

I am a student of automotive engineering and I want to learn programming. 
I also want to ask if programming would actually be useful in my field and if so, what type of language should I learn?

Answer (score 4):

Programming is a useful skill in almost every field, especially for all sorts of engineering majors.

Specific language, on the other hand, is less important. I suggest you take a look at the programming and other CS courses provided by your university.

In addition, I suggest you seek the advice of your student/study counsellor. After all, they were hired to give this sort of advice to students.